# I have spliced the data coming from an api to get the first 8 items. How do I convert this spliced data to two decimal places?

Tags: javascript

This is my code. I want to round the variable element to 2 decimal places. How do I proceed?

```
computed:{
    computedCrypto(){
    const element = this.limit ? this.crypto_data.slice(3,this.limit) : this.crypto_data
    for (let index = 0; index < element.length; index++) {
        console.log(element[index].price_usd.toFixed(2)) 
    }      
  }

  },

    
   
   

     
  }
```

Comment: `.toFixed(2)` looks right

Comment: but what is `fanta`? It seems you mean `index < element.length;` but then you're shadowing the outer `element` by declaring an inner variable of the same name.

Comment: @JaromandaX how do i attach it to the function? That's the issue

Comment: attach what to which function?

Comment: @pilchard fanta is just something i was trying out to give an idea of what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: return element.toFixed(2) throws an error viz element.toFixed is not a function @JaromandaX

Comment: I never suggested `element.toFixed(2)` ... I was referring to the code you WROTE as a COMMENT - i.e. `fanta[index].price_usd.toFixed(2)`

Comment: alright @JaromandaX. I've edited the code a bit to                                        
    computed:{
    computedCrypto(){
    const element = this.limit ? this.crypto_data.slice(3,this.limit) : this.crypto_data
    for (let index = 0; index < element.length; index++) {
        console.log(element[index].price_usd.toFixed(2)) 
    }      
  }

  }, This logs the correct rounded up values. How do i "return" thses values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commented out attempt is close, but suffers a few problems mostly to do with variable naming. To keep using a `for` loop you need to access the appropriate array, and either mutate or clone and reassign each object (here using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) while also reassigning each `price_usd` value using [`toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) as you were attempting. You'll note that I'm also `slice()`ing the `crypto_data` array even if there isn't a `limit` set in order to avoid mutating the original array.

```js
class Example {

  constructor(limit) {
    this.crypto_data = [...Array(10).keys()].map(() => ({ price_usd: Math.random() * 10 }));
    this.limit = limit ?? 0;
  }

  computedCrypto() {
    const data = this.limit ? this.crypto_data.slice(3, this.limit) : this.crypto_data.slice();
    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
      data[index] = {
        ...data[index],
        price_usd: data[index].price_usd.toFixed(2)
      };
    }
    return data;
  }
}

const example = new Example(5);
console.log(example.computedCrypto());

const exampleNoLimit = new Example();
console.log(exampleNoLimit.computedCrypto());
```

A more succinct version could be written using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
computedCrypto() {
  const data = this.limit
    ? this.crypto_data.slice(3, this.limit)
    : this.crypto_data;

  return data.map(o => ({ ...o, price_usd: o.price_usd.toFixed(2) }));
}
```